# Apache on Mac Mavericks 10.9, works, but getting some warnings

Tags: macos, apache, osx-mavericks, httpd.conf

I`m getting some warnings, here is what the prompt returns to me.

```
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

The localhot is working fine, but I do not know if these errors will interfere.

Note: I'm with MAMP installed to, but I want to use only the apache that comes with mac.

Comment: It sounds like some other process (possibly the MAMP version of apache) is already running and has grabbed port 80.

Comment: And this is a serious error or can I ignore it? Thanks!

Comment: Serious. If I'm right, it means you aren't running the web server software you think you are.